# 2D variable name in Django sessions

Tags: django, session

I am trying to create a 2D variable name in sessions as in the Django docs example at this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20use%20sessions%C2%B6%20%201%20Enabling,first%20argument%20to...%204%20Settings%0A%C2%B6.%20%20More%20):

It says:

```
# Gotcha: Session is NOT modified, because this alters
# request.session['foo'] instead of request.session.
request.session['foo']['bar'] = 'baz'
```

but when i use that code, i get: `KeyError: 'foo'`

if i create 'foo' first with `request.session.get('foo', 'baz')`,
then `request.session['foo']['bar'] = 'bam'`

i still get: `KeyError: 'foo'`

why am i not able to set a 2d variable as in the django doc example? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`request.session.get('foo', 'baz')` don't create anything.
Are you mean:

```
request.session.setdefault('foo', 'baz')
```

If you Set 'baz' in `request.session['foo']`
`type(request.session['foo'])` is a String
You can Not do `String['bar']`, therefore
`request.session['foo']['bar'] = 'bam'` not work.

What you really want to do? Why you need 2d Parameter?

Comment: I thought a 2D parameter would help with clearing old data from the db by deleting all user session data when the cookie expires, using a 2D parameter. But now I think maybe it doesn't matter because the 1d param is still connected to the session and should expire at the same time as the cookie. I'm still confused why the Django docs show a 2D param if it doesn't work. But I will try to work through and understand your reply. Thank you for it.